# Null hypothesis in permutation inference for the general linear model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, permutation-test

I'm currently studying [a paper by Winkler et. al](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811914000913#bb0205) on permutation inference for the general linear model and am confused by their reasoning and notation.

They first introduce a formulation for the general linear model:

> Y
> =
> M
> ψ
> +
> ϵ     (Eq. 1)
>
> where Y is the N × 1 vector of observed data, M is the full-rank N × r
> design matrix that includes all effects of interest as well as all
> modelled nuisance effects, ψ is the r × 1 vector of r regression
> coefficients, and ϵ is the N × 1 vector of random errors.

Regarding the null hypothesis, it is stated that:

> Our interest is to test the null hypothesis that an arbitrary
> combination (contrast) of some or all of these parameters is equal to
> zero, i.e., H0 : C′ψ = 0, where C is a r × s full-rank matrix of s
> contrasts, 1 ≤ s ≤ r.

The general formulation (Eq. 1) in the first quote can be transformed into a partioned one:

> Y
> =
> X
> β
> +
> Z
> γ
> +
> ϵ     (Eq. 2)
>
> where X is the matrix with regressors of interest, Z is the matrix
> with nuisance regressors, and β and γ are the vectors of regression
> coefficients.

When discussing the Freedman-Lane procedure for permutation inference in the following it is stated that:

> The rationale for this permutation method is that, if the null hypothesis is true, then β = 0 [...]

These paragraphs pose two questions to me:

1. What does C′ in H0 : C′ψ = 0 denote mathematically speaking, given that C is a matrix?
2. How does C′ψ = 0 imply β = 0? Is the reasoning C′ψ = 0, therefore Y = M0 + ϵ = X0 + Z0  + ϵ = ϵ valid?

Thanks a lot in advance, I'd be very grateful for help or advice on how to approach/present this problem in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C` matrix just indicates which slopes, or linear combinations of slopes, is equal to 0.  If you want to test that the first slope is 0 (but the remaining can be anything) then `C` will just be a vector with the first element $1$ and the remaining elements are $0$.  If you want to test that the first 3 slopes are all 0, then `C` is a 3x3 identity matrix with the remaining rows equal to $0$.  This is the simple case which leads to $\beta=0$ for a set of the slopes.  But is also more general in that you could test if $\beta_1 = \beta_2$ by setting the first column of `C` to $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer! I do however have a basic follow up question:
If  `C` is a `r x s` matrix that indicates which slopes are equal to zero and `ψ` a `r x 1` vector that contains the slopes/regression coefficients themselves, how can `C′ψ` result in a scalar as stated in the null hypothesis (`C′ψ = 0`). Shouldn't the result always be of form of a `r x 1` vector?

Comment: @AdrianMak, the null can be a scalar if you only have one contrast ($s=1$), but in general the right side of the null hypothesis is a vector of $0$'s, each contrast is equal to 0.

Comment: Okay thanks, allow me one last question: In `C′ψ = 0`, what does ` ′ ` indicate? Because from all of your answers, it just seems like `C`and `ψ` are just multiplied in the null hypothesis.

Comment: The prime "'" indicates the transpose of  the C matrix.